# Read Model Attributes in html body onload

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to know is following is possible to do. If 'yes' what is the issue here

I am passing a model attribute from controller

```
    public String home(Model model , @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", name = "customerID") Long  customerId) {

    model.addAttribute("customerID", customerId);
    return "userhome";
}
```

I want to call perform some operations (change background color of the element with id=customerID). Since there is no event to trigger this such as button click i'm doing this using html body onclick. Thymeleaf also used here.

```
    <body th:onload="setInitialFormatting(${customerID})">
    ...
    </body>
```

javascript function:

```
    function setInitialFormatting(customerID) {
        document.getElementById(customerID).style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
```

But I get the following error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Does there come an actual attribute? With the ID customerID? You can check this in F12 in browser at "Elements". If so your javascript onclick might not work, try console.log("test"); inside the function setInitialFormatting() if you see in ur console: test then you atleast know the function works. if that works your change color function does not work, but I think that works fine. Using double quotes (" ") instead of single at bgColor = 'red' might be a thing. If none of this works I need more information or I am just not able to help haha.

Comment: Bit late. I suggest you call your function on a document.ready script. In this function you can have a variable with the model attribute you passed, in the shape of: var x = [[${customerID}]];